Developer Console - exporting query results
Export Results from Developer Console - Query Editor?
@NGix provided this console command in response to the above request.
I am hoping that someone could help me understand what it is doing and how
And/Or
help me modify it to pull the results of a "Search in Files" rather than a SOQL query.
var o = document.evaluate("//div[@id='editors-body']/div[not(contains(@style,'display:none') or contains(@style,'display: none'))]//table/tbody/tr",document,null,0,null);
var r = [];
while(row = o.iterateNext()){
    var cols = row.getElementsByTagName('td');
    var a = [];

    for(var i=0; i<cols.length; i++){
        a.push( formatData( cols[i].textContent ) );
    }

    r.push( a );
}

// generating csv file
var csv = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,filename=download.csv,";
var rows = [];

for(var i=0; i<r.length; i++){
    rows.push( r[i].join(",") );
}

csv += rows.join('\r\n');

popup(csv);

function formatData(input) {
    // replace " with “
    var regexp = new RegExp(/["]/g);
    var output = input.replace(regexp, "“");
    //HTML
    var regexp = new RegExp(/\<[^\<]+\>/g);
    var output = output.replace(regexp, "");
    if (output == "") return '';
    return '"' + output + '"';
}

// showing data in window for copy/ paste
function popup(data) {
    var generator = window.open('', 'csv', 'height=400,width=600');
    generator.document.write('<html><head><title>CSV</title>');
    generator.document.write('</head><body style="overflow: hidden;">');
    generator.document.write('<a href="'+encodeURI(csv)+'" download="Sf_export.csv">Download CSV</a><br>');
    generator.document.write('<textArea style="width: 100%; height: 97%;" wrap="off" >');
    generator.document.write(data);
    generator.document.write('</textArea>');
    generator.document.write('</body></html>');
    generator.document.close();
    return true;
}


I was able to figure out the solution,
it only required:

locating the overarching div containing the SearchinFiles
updating the document.evaluate() to match

I hope this helps anyone who is struggling with the same, and a big THANK YOU to @NGix for providing this solution!
// Instructions:
// 1. Open the soql query result page in Salesforce Dev Console
// 2. Open the browser console (F12 or right click -> inspect -> console)
// 3. Paste the code below and hit enter
// 4. A new window will open with the CSV data - be sure to allow popups
// 5. Click the "Download CSV" link to download the file

var o = document.evaluate("//div[@id='searchInFilesWindow']/div[not(contains(@style,'display:none') or contains(@style,'display: none'))]//table/tbody/tr",document,null,0,null);
var r = [];
while(row = o.iterateNext()){
    var cols = row.getElementsByTagName('td');
    var a = [];

    for(var i=0; i<cols.length; i++){
        a.push( formatData( cols[i].textContent ) );
    }

    r.push( a );
}

// generating csv file
var csv = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,filename=download.csv,";
var rows = [];

for(var i=0; i<r.length; i++){
    rows.push( r[i].join(",") );
}

csv += rows.join('\r\n');

popup(csv);

function formatData(input) {
    // replace " with “
    var regexp = new RegExp(/["]/g);
    var output = input.replace(regexp, "“");
    //HTML
    var regexp = new RegExp(/\<[^\<]+\>/g);
    var output = output.replace(regexp, "");
    if (output == "") return '';
    return '"' + output + '"';
}

// showing data in window for copy/ paste
function popup(data) {
    var generator = window.open('', 'csv', 'height=400,width=600');
    generator.document.write('<html><head><title>CSV</title>');
    generator.document.write('</head><body style="overflow: hidden;">');
    generator.document.write('<a href="'+encodeURI(csv)+'" download="Sf_export.csv">Download CSV</a><br>');
    generator.document.write('<textArea style="width: 100%; height: 97%;" wrap="off" >');
    generator.document.write(data);
    generator.document.write('</textArea>');
    generator.document.write('</body></html>');
    generator.document.close();
    return true;
}

